# Time-based workflow causing Flow with Email Alerts to fail

Tags: visual-workflow, email-alert, bulkification

I have a time-based workflow that checks a checkbox on an Account which causes a flow to run and send a set of emails to  maybe 1-6 contacts via Workflow Email Alerts. The end of the flow un-checks this checkbox to clear back the status ready for the next run at some-point in the future.

What I've found is that the flow doesn't run when there are a number (probably more than 10 - not sure exact number) of Accounts to be processed at one time. The emails don't send and the checkbox is left checked. I haven't managed to capture debug logs and haven't seen any error emails come in.

I understand that 'batching' takes place from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=5) but considerations are only mentioned for Apex. Could this be the problem?

What are the considerations if a Flow to be used to do the email send as opposed to Apex when time-based workflow is used? (Usually I would use Apex but as we're actively encouraged to use Flows I'm wondering if this is a usecase where Flows can't do the process required.) And also, are there any design patterns that would mitigate any issues with bulkification and flows?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Flows are bulkified. Everything in a record-triggered flow and the associated triggers, process builders and workflows will run in one transaction. If you go over limits or end up with an error, nothing will commit. Exceptions exist (flows can generate multiple trx).

As far as I can remember there is a limit of 10 emails to one transaction. My experience suggests that cc/bcc does not count toward this limit.

You can use scheduled-path in triggered flows in this case. Scheduled path is an exception to the rule and every scheduled path should execute as a separate transaction.

As far as bypassing to 10 limit; you can use the send better email unofficial SF component and bcc email addresses if your email notification is generic. Another approach could be to divide the batch into multiple scheduled paths so that you don't go over the 10 limit.

Comment: I think the issue I have is that the time based workflow 'engine' is batching the Account updates and so the limits are hit. AFAIK I have no control over this and so cannot solve the problem as the batch size could be a number over which the limits are breached.

Seems like we can't have flows that run Email Alerts (or even complex processes) when time-based workflow could be the running mechanism as script timeout or or limit exceptions could be thrown. (If using apex batch at least I can set the batch size to be small enough that these limits go away...)

Comment: I think this is the limit you are facing: https://www.forcetalks.com/salesforce-topic/what-is-the-governor-limit-of-sendemail-to-sent-bulk-email/#:~:text=If%20emails%20are%20sent%20via,per%20day%20to%20external%20addresses.